# Creation of 3D ojects undergoing non-isometric transformations

Tags: python, object, 3d

I am currently working on a research project focused on predicting transformations in 3D objects caused by natural growth factors. The project utilizes point cloud representations, and while I cannot disclose my confidential dataset, I am seeking a suitable representable dataset for publication purposes. However, most publicly available 3D datasets lack a time dimension, making them unsuitable for addressing this specific problem.

The ideal dataset I am looking for should consist of objects represented by sets of points in 3D space, with two time dimensions. In the second time dimension, the objects should have undergone non-isometric transformations. These transformations should vary across objects, while still maintaining a degree of overall similarity. Additionally, it would be beneficial if the objects within and between instances were aligned (so no isometric transformation such as rotation and translation), thereby eliminating the need for alignment algorithms such as ICP.

I have identified two potential solutions to acquire such a dataset:
-Modifying existing 3D objects: One approach involves modifying objects from publicly available datasets. However, a challenge with this approach is that the objects may not be perfectly aligned, necessitating the use of alignment algorithms like ICP. Additionally, ensuring consistent and meaningful modifications across objects to reflect the desired transformations presents another challenge and often does not make intuitive sense in the case of objects representing planes, etc.

-Creating geometrical objects: Alternatively, I can generate geometric objects myself and potentially combine multiple shapes to form two complex objects. Where they both refer to before and after transformation. By introducing noise to the point cloud data, I can ensure that object instances differ while maintaining an overall transformation pattern that can be predicted.

I am mostly invested in the second approach, and I was wondering if there are some available python packages that would make life easier in creating these 3D objects and applying noise? Also, how can I start creating the objects in 3D space.

If you have any other ideas or suggestions or if there are any aspects I may have overlooked, please feel free to share them. I am open to exploring alternative approaches or techniques that may enhance the quality and effectiveness of my research. Thanks in advance!

Best,
Rvandossie